# Php string - use pattern in string to break into array

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have a string that is something like this:

```
$string = "Item 1|Item 2|Item 3|Item 4|Item 5"
```

What is the best way to iterate through this string and remove duplicates.  So for example it would know that each portion of code to compare would be between the '|' characters.

It would select Item1 and `preg_replace()` the rest of the string with that Item.  Then it would look at the next Item (Item2) and `preg_replace()` the rest of the string with that Item.

The tricky part is if `Item 1 == Item 2`.  Then, the algorithm will replace Item 2 and Item 3 will be the next Item to look at.

I have tried a couple methods but nothing is working.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, ignoring all your stuff about `preg_replace()` if you are really just looking to remove duplicates, then use a few array operations.

`explode()` it on the `|` into an array.  Filter it with `array_unique()` and `implode()` it back into pipe-delimited string:

```
$array = explode("|", "Item 1|Item 2|Item 3|Item 4|Item 5");
$unique = array_unique($array);
implode("|", $unique);
```

Comment: Great! I would be embarrassed to show how I was TRYING to do it.  Many Thanks!

Comment: @thepristinedesign: So, where in this are you doing a preg_replace?

Comment: I was intending to use preg_replace() but the explode-implode method looks MUCH more elegant and efficient.

Answer (score 4):

```
$items = explode('|',$string);
$unique_items = array_unique($items);
$unique_string = implode('|', $unique_items);
```